Build fail with netlify DecapCMS
Every time an update on the DecapCMS UI goes through, netlify is updated and the site deploys and rebuilds. The build always seems to fail with an error similar to this:
error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
7:47:34 PM:       Field "featuredImage" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields.
7:47:34 PM:       This can happen if you e.g. accidentally added { } to the field "featuredImage". If you didn't expect "featuredImage" to be of type "String" make sure that your input source and/or plugin is correct.
      However, if you expect "featuredImage" to exist, the field might be accessible in another subfield. Please try your query in GraphiQL.
7:47:34 PM:       It is recommended to explicitly type your GraphQL schema if you want to use optional fields.

When I manually click "trigger deploy, clear cache and deploy", then it builds successfully. For some reason it isn't seeing the update until the cache is cleared manually on netlify. I need to find a way for this to not happen so I dont have to manually go in to trigger a deploy
I've tried adding the build command in package.json as: "build": "gatsby clean && gatsby build --log-pages"
And in netlify.toml as:
[build]
  base = "/"
  publish = "public"
  command = "gatsby clean && gatsby build"

It runs in the deploy as gatsby clean && gatsby build but the cache isn't cleared the same as when I manually trigger a deploy and clear the cache. How can I add something in the code so that this happens automatically everytime a decapCMS edit is made.

Any suggestions here? The reason I'm calling a GraphQL query is because I've set up the decap CMS with GatsbyJS app.
